# preg_match pattern for steamid

Tags: regex, preg-match, steam

what is the correct pattern to check string which contains only numbers like this `76561197960265728`?

I've tried to check with `var_dump(preg_match('/(\d+)/', '76561197960265728'));` but it returns true no matter if there will be letters or symbols in string or not.

Comment: use anchors :- `^(\d+)$`

Comment: Add anchors: `'/^\d+$/'`

Comment: thanks, solved very fast!